# Rewrite SQL query for PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I want to rewrite this SQL query for PostgreSQL

```
SELECT A.* FROM (SELECT B.*, ROWNUM RN FROM (SELECT Y.COMPONENTSTATSID, Y.NAME, Y.SERIALNUMBER, Y.WEIGHTKG, Y.ZONECAGE, Y.POWERWATT, Y.MANIFACTURECOMPANY, Y.UFORM, Y.STATUS, Y.LOCATION, Y.HEATEMISIONSBTU, Y.PRODUCTIONENVIRONMENT, Y.STANDARTLIFETIME, Y.OPERATINGHAMIDITYRANGE,  Y.OPERATINGSYSTEM, Y.DATEDEPLOYED, Y.INTERFACETYPE, Y.TYPE, Y.COOLINGCAPACITYBTU, Y.DATEADDED, Y.DESCRIPTION  FROM COMPONENTWEIGHT X, COMPONENTSTATS Y WHERE X.COMPONENTSTATSID = Y.COMPONENTSTATSID AND Y.COMPONENTTYPEID = 3300 ORDER BY %S %S) B  WHERE ROWNUM <= ?) A WHERE RN > ?
```

I tried this `SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY %S %S offset ? limit ?`

I tried to implement the code for lazy loading(limit the rows per page) but it's not working properly because the queries are wrong. Please ignore the table columns I need just to properly limit the rows result.

Comment: You should describe what you want to do or at least format your query so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use rownum, use [LIMIT and OFFSET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-limit.html).

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT how_many_rows
OFFSET starting_after_row_number
```